# Alternate flex direction based on its parent

Tags: css, sass

I am creating a flex responsive layout.

I have a navigation bar on the left in the desktop version which becomes a top navigation bar on mobile (using media-query)

```
  flex-direction: row;

  @media (min-width: 600px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

That's great, but I want all of its sub-elements to have flex-direction of column (if parent had flex-direction of row), and vice versa... and that continues for about 3-4 depth, with each layer alternating in comparison to its parent (that means that it is going to look like: col -> row -> col -> row or row->col->row->col).

Any easy way of doing this without continuing to media-query all the way to the 4th depth elements?

I did try using variables (I work with SASS), but it seems those variables only get rendered once, and are not "reactive".

I am aiming towards a css/scss solution only btw.

Thanks

Comment: share your code, there is probably a different solution to what you aim to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you want the direct child to be the opposite of your parent you can style the direct child with the same media query.

this would get ALL `.row > .col`

assuming markup like:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.row {
  flex-direction: row;

  @media (min-width: 600px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  & > .col {
    flex-direction: column;

    @media (min-width: 600px) and (orientation:landscape) {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to target the highest `.row` you would need a top-level modifier class or a parent class above `.row`, e.g. `class="row row--top"` or `.parent-class > .row`